# Failure of Castle Winsor 3.0 NuGet installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, nuget, windsor-3.0

I'm trying to install Castle Windsor 3.0 using NuGet, and it fails with the following message:

```
PM> Install-Package Castle.Windsor
'Castle.Core (≥ 3.0.0)' not installed. Attempting to retrieve dependency from source...
Done.
Install-Package : Id is required.
Version is required.
Authors is required.
Description is required.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Castle.Windsor
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet
```

I've tried it both using the command-line (above) and using the Library Package Manager.

My environment is a default MVC3.0 installation, using the web site template, in Visual Studio 2010, with absolutely nothing changed from the defaults.

The error looks like there is something wrong with the package being downloaded from NuGet.

Can anyone shed any light on this?  I can work around it with a manual install of Castle Windsor, but would like to use NuGet if possible.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Not sure why it's saying `Id is required.` but can you try calling out the specific version? This morning, it's `Install-Package Castle.Windsor -version 3.0.0.4001`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David, but I still received the same type of error when specifying the version.  I've tried installing NUnit with NuGet and this works fine, so seems to be something specific to Windsor, rather than NuGet.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of NuGet--1.6 I think? You might have to reinstall as administrator as I recall.

Comment: Excellent suggestion David.  I was using NuGet 1.1, and when I replaced this with 1.6, the install worked fine.  That's rather a short forward-compatibility lifetime for NuGet, but useful to know for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update NuGet to the latest version. I recently upgraded from 1.3 to 1.6, but had to completely reinstall (as administrator) to get my project working. I think it was for a FluentValidation.MVC3 project I was whipping up.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem even having the latest version of NuGet. I had to settle for:

```
Install-Package Castle.Core -Version 2.5.2
```